# bash: set environment variable out of find's exec

Tags: bash, find, environment-variables, env

I would like to find all directories in the current working directory and its subdirectories, that are either the root of a git repository, or not tracked by git at all.

To do so I wrote this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FOUND_UNTRACKED=0
export FOUND_TRACKED=
find . -type d \( \( -exec test -d {}\.git \; -exec /bin/bash -c "export FOUND_TRACKED=$1:$FOUND_TRACKED" {} \; -prune \) -o -exec echo Untracked directory: {} \; -exec /bin/bash -c "export FOUND_UNTRACKED=1" \; \)

echo $FOUND_UNTRACKED
echo $FOUND_TRACKED
```

The find works fine, but unfortunately the changes to the environment variable inside the exec are not propagated. Ie, `FOUND_TRACKED` is always empty, `FOUND_UNTRACKED` is 0.

Any idea how to get this stuff working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process **inherits** the environment from a parent. There is no easy mechanism to affect a parent's environment: the child process can change its own environment, but that is simply thrown away when the child exits. You bash script launches `find` in a child process, which in turn launches another `bash` in a further subprocess.

One way to get around this problem is to cause the child process to create output, which the parent then interprets. Here's a simple example:

```
files="$( /bin/ls )"
if [ "$files" ]; then
    echo "found some files"
else
    echo "no files there"
fi
```

If you need more complicated feedback from a child process, you can create a temporary file (using `mktemp`) in the parent, and get the child processes to save their output to that, so that you can process the output in the parent once the children complete.

Answer (score 0):

Move the export outside of find, as that will run in a subshell, so any exported variables would only lie in that shell.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the other answers - I cant find the utility of your find expression for a git user.  The .git dir is only at the root ... so you end up reporting sub-directories of git as 'not tracked' which is not true.

This is different from other SCMs like CVS where there is a CVS dir at every directory level